# Print Count before the range being counted JAVA

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, count

Okay, I am trying to make a program for calculating leap years in Java. That part of the program works fine. The program prompts the user for 2 years (start and end) and then prints only the leap years. After the leap years print, there is a count of how many were printed.

Everything up until this point works perfectly fine. Now my question is how to print the count BEFORE the actual leap years print? I believe that i would have to either print to a list or an array and then display the count and then call the array/list to print after the fact. However i believe that i am making this too complicated, is there an easier way? please help.

```
import java.util.Scanner; //Imports Scanner to gather user input.

public class Program
{
    public static void println(Object arg) //Shortens to println to make coding easier to read/follow.
    {
        System.out.println(arg); //prints on new line
    }

    public static void print(Object arg) //Shortens to print to make coding easier to read/follow.
    {
        System.out.print(arg); //prints on current line
    }

    public static void run()
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); //Defines Scanner to gather keyboard input.

        println("Leap Years");
        println("");

        print("Enter the starting year: " );
        while (!in.hasNextInt()) //This loop verifys that the input from the user is numerical and prompts to try again if not.
        {
            print("Numbers only! Enter the starting year: ");
            in.next();
        }
        int y1 = in.nextInt();

        while (y1 <1582) //Leap year was not established until 1582, this while loop ensures no dates before that time.
        {
        println("ERROR: Leap year was not implemented until 1582.");
        print("Enter the starting year: " );
        while (!in.hasNextInt()) 
        {
            print("Numbers only! Enter the starting year: ");
            in.next();
        }
        y1 = in.nextInt();
        }

        print("Enter the ending year: " );
        while (!in.hasNextInt()) 
        {
            print("Numbers only! Enter the ending year: ");
            in.next();
        }
        int y2 = in.nextInt();

        while (y2<y1) //This prevents the user from creating a reverse range.
        {
        println("ERROR: Ending year must not precede starting year.");
        print("Enter the ending year: " );
        while (!in.hasNextInt()) 
        {
            print("Numbers only! Enter the ending year: ");
            in.next();
        }
        y2 = in.nextInt();
        }

        println("");
        println("Leap years according to the Gregorian calendar from "+y1+" to "+y2+":");
        println("");
        int c=0; //Defines the count of leap years
        for(int year=y1; year<=y2; year++) //Prints all years from user range.
        {
           if((year % 400 == 0) || ((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0))) //Prints only leap years from user range.
           {
               ++c;
               println(year);
           }
        }
        println("");
        if(c>1 || c==0)
        println("There are "+c+" leap years in this range.");
        else
        println("There is "+c+" leap year in this range.");
    }
}
```

Thanks

EDIT
currently the output looks like this:

1
2
3
...
There are "x" leap years in this range.

I want the output to look like this:

There are "x" leap years in this range.

1
2
3
...

Comment: Why don't you save all leap years into an array then you can print out the count and then all the leap year at the end of main()

Comment: I am unsure of how to "save" the leap years into an array to recall later. and when i google i just seem to be unable to word my search correctly and get ArrayList responses for strings etc.

Comment: instead of using int, you could use Integer so you can add to arraylist (if you can't, I will post more clearly answer when I get my PC on)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your code to sth like this:

```
public static void run()
{
//anything....
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
println("");
println("Leap years according to the Gregorian calendar from "+y1+" to "+y2+":");
println("");
for(Integer year=y1; year<=y2; year++) //Prints all years from user range.
{
   if((year % 400 == 0) || ((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0))) //Prints only leap years from user range.
   {
        list.add(year);
   }
}
//Loop and print size() and all leap years here
```

Comment: i tried this method and ended up with the same result as the first answer where i get the count first but then i get 1 result from the range, then a count, then a single range. and the count is off for this. i guess i don't know how to loop and print size() correctly. Is this replacing my int c for my counter and i have to print the list myself? im still confused...

Comment: Nevermind, i figured it out. now it works correctly, i just used:

list.size and println(list); and everything worked fine. im such a dork.

THANK YOU!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Simply move the printing operation to the middle of the loop to print the increment.

```
for(int year=y1; year<=y2; year++)
    {
       if((year % 400 == 0) || ((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0)))
       {
           ++c;
           System.out.println(c);
           println(year);
       }
    }
```

Or, if for some reason you only want it to print ONCE, as your question is somewhat unclear, you can move the println() to the outside of the loop before it begins, but it will print 0 every time.

Comment: I want to print the final count once, then display the range of years.